# How to calculate run-time memory address of relocated references

Tags: linker, operating-system

When I do homework on  *Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective 2nd Edition*, I find a question in chapter 7, the question is

> The swap routine in Figure 7.10 contains five relocated references. For each relocated reference, give its line number in Figure 7.10, its run-time memory address, and its value. The original code and relocation entries in the swap.o module are shown in Figure 7.19.

and these are two pictures 7.10 and 7.19

[picture7.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97KMN.png)

[picture7.19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIVsQ.png)

and I found the solution on website is

```
 Line # in Fig. 7.10      Address        Value

      15(bufp0)          0x080483CB    0x0804945c
      16(buf[1])         0x080483D0    0x08049458 
      18(bufp1)          0x080483D8    0x08049548
      18(buf[1])         0x080483DC    0x08049458
      23(bufp1)          0x080483E7    0x08049548
```

I don't know how to calculate the address.

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it**.*

Comment: Sorry, but actually, this is not my homework, I just look this by myself, and I have read the example before this question for 2 hours, but I have no idea how to calculate the address,  the example of absolute references before this question is too ambiguous, and it use the address of  buf(0x8049454), but I can't find the connection between them.

Comment: **When I do homework** is how you began your question.

Comment: Because it was called "homework problems" in this book, so I said when I do homework.

Comment: I commented about your saying you were doing homework, to which you replied *It's not homework*. I then quoted directly from your post which says *homework*, and again you repeat *It's not homework*. What is your point? Your question **still** says it's homework.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language, maybe I misunderstand what you said. What I mean is "this is not a homework like that teachers give us, it is not like quizzes or assignments, I do it just for interesting and want to improve my ability." And why I said when I do homework is because this question called "homework problems", it just like practice for me. I am sorry that I can't express clearly, or 'homework' is a different meaning in different culture. Do you think it is a good idea to delete "when I do homework" in question?

Comment: I suggest getting a new book. I have NEVER seen relocation done like this. I can see why you are confused.

Comment: OK, Thank you for your help